# Aggregating MDX query results on existing facts only

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, cube

I am very new to MDX, so probably I'm missing something very simple.

In my cube, I have a dimension `[Asset]` and a measure `[Visits]`, calculating (in this case) how many visits an asset has been consumed by. An important thing to note is that not every visit is associated with an asset.

What I need to find out is how many visits there are that consumed at least one asset. I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT
  [Asset].[All] ON COLUMNS,
  [Measures].[Visits] ON ROWS
FROM
  [Analytics]
```

But this query just returns the total number of visits in the cube. I tried applying the `NON EMPTY` modifier to both axes, but that doesn't help.

Comment: What are the levels of your ``Asset`` hierarchy?

Comment: @Benoit there's only one level—`Asset Name`

Comment: Does this query returns visits that are not associated to assets?
``SELECT [Asset].[Asset Name].Members ON COLUMNS, [Measures].[Visits] ON ROWS FROM [Analytics]``

Comment: @Benoit Well, it returns the whole set of `[Asset]` members, including `All`. For each particular asset, of course, the number of visits is right. But `All` still shows the total number of visits in the cube. And by the way, I cannot just calculate a sum of all visits values per asset, since it is a many-to-many relationship, meaning that a single visit can consume multiple assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should give you what you expect:

```
WITH MEMBER [Asset].[Asset Name].[All Assets] AS
  AGGREGATE( EXCEPT( [Asset].[Asset Name].MEMBERS, { [Asset].[All] } ) )
SELECT
  { [Asset].[Asset Name].[All Assets] } ON COLUMNS,
  [Measures].[Visits] ON ROWS
FROM
  [Analytics]
```

You may need to put `{[Asset].[Asset Name].[All]}` as second argument of Except if the All member was not excluded.

In the query I create a calculated member `[Asset].[Asset Name].[all assets]` that should represent all your existing assets. I supposed that your existing assets are all the members of the level `[Asset].[Asset Name]` but the `All` member.

You can find more information about the Aggregate function [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145524).

Comment: This seems to _almost_ work. It gives me `114370`, while the correct amount should be `116092`. Can you explain how your query works?

Comment: @Shedal I added explanations to my answer.

Comment: I understand your logic, and it seems valid to me. But still, for some reason it doesn't work as expected. Maybe it's because it is a many-to-many relationship, maybe for some other reason... But what if we approach it from a different side - why does the "All" member include all data? Maybe there's a setting somewhere, changing it behaviour?

Comment: It seems that the wrong number is an error in my cube, not in your query. Thanks for your help, marking the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This works as well:

```
SELECT
  [Measures].[Visits] ON 0
FROM
  [Analytics]
WHERE
  DRILLDOWNLEVEL([Asset].[All])
```

**Update:** as well as this:

```
SELECT
  [Measures].[Visits] ON 0
FROM
  [Analytics]
WHERE
  [Asset].[All].CHILDREN
```